# Why does my code generate different results each time i run it?

Tags: python

I want to use the alpha vantage api to extact the data of a list of companies (48 companies).

But the outputs are compeletely different each time and it keeps changing. Frankly, i didn't change my coding.  Is there  anything wrong with the coding or  somethingelse happened?

(I'm pretty new to the programming world so forgive me if I said or made something stupid.)

```
#define your company_name

tickers = {}  # create an empty dictionary to store the ticker symbols

for company_name in org_names:
    # define the url for the search based on the documentation
    url = f'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords={company_name}&apikey={api_key}'

    # call the API and return the response as json data
    response = requests.get(url)
    ticker = response.json()

    # extract the best match from the response that has XETRA as region
    best_match = None
    for match in ticker.get('bestMatches', []): 
        if match.get('4. region') == 'XETRA':   
            best_match = match  
            break   
    
    # if no match with XETRA region, select the first match 
    if best_match is None and len(ticker.get('bestMatches', [])) > 0:          
        best_match = ticker['bestMatches'][0]   
    
    # add the best match to the dictionary
    tickers[company_name] = best_match

    time.sleep(1)  # add a delay of 1 second to avoid hitting API rate limits
```

tickers

**The ideal result should looks like:**

```
'BASF': {'1. symbol': 'BAS.DEX',
  '2. name': 'BASF SE NA O.N.',
  '3. type': 'Equity',
  '4. region': 'XETRA',
  '5. marketOpen': '08:00',
  '6. marketClose': '20:00',
  '7. timezone': 'UTC+02',
  '8. currency': 'EUR',
  '9. matchScore': '0.6000'}
```

for all the 48 companies, and i do successed once.  How can i get the ideal output for all the companies in the org_names list?

Comment: How is your output differing? Do you have examples?

Comment: I suspect the API is returning different results each time. It probably has a limit on the number of matches, and if there are too many possibilities it returns a random selection of them. Or maybe the order is different each time, so the first one that matches `XETRA` will be different.

Comment: thank u for the comment. the format is the same but the companies shown in the output list is different from time to time.(e.g. 1st run returns BASF, Hellofresh. 2nd run returns SAP and BASF).  If i run the code for individual companies one by one ,then the output is fine. however, when i try to loop them, things getting strange.